# why mybatis not provide pagination query?

Tags: pagination, mybatis

Spring data jpa has Pagination query and there are also many need paging scenarios,why mybatis only provide `selectList`?How to implement pagination in mybatis ?Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: You may use a plugin known as Mybatis-PageHelper (https://github.com/pagehelper/Mybatis-PageHelper) to help you on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an instance of `RowBounds` for pagination something like:

```
mybatisTemplate.selectList("query", params, new RowBounds(offset, limit));
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Mybatis-PageHelper

add in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.pagehelper</groupId>
    <artifactId>pagehelper</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

configure in mybatis-config.xml
where database supported are oracle, mysql, mariadb, sqlite, hsqldb, postgresql, db2, sqlserver, informix, h2, sqlserver2012, derby

```
<!-- 
    In the configuration file, 
    plugins location must meet the requirements as the following order:
    properties?, settings?, 
    typeAliases?, typeHandlers?, 
    objectFactory?,objectWrapperFactory?, 
    plugins?, 
    environments?, databaseIdProvider?, mappers?
-->
<plugins>
    <plugin interceptor="com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor">
        <!-- config params as the following -->
        <property name="param1" value="value1"/>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

example of usage:

```
mybatisTemplate.selectList("query", params, new RowBounds(offset, limit));
```

consequence:
1) you don't have to implement pagination in your sql
2) mybatis-pagehelper will **generate** the required pagination sql

Hope the above helps

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis is an unlike ORM framework, it only provides a mapping engine that maps SQL results to object trees in a declarative way.

Most databases have their own paging query dialect, For examples:

MySQL

```sql
select * from table limit 0, 10
```

PostgreSQL

```sql
select * from table limit 10 OFFSET 0
```

Oracle

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT tta.*, ROWNUM AS trn FROM (select * from table) tta WHERE ROWNUM <= 10) pta WHERE trn > 0
```

---

MyBatis allows you to intercept calls to at certain points within the execution of a mapped statement, you can implement a pagination plugin, docs: [MyBatis Plugins](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#plugins).

---

If you just want to use a pagination plugin, You can try [MyPages](https://github.com/yihleego/mypages).

For example on the `Spring Boot`:

Maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.leego</groupId>
    <artifactId>mypages-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
mypages.page-field=page
mypages.size-field=size
```

Mapper

```java
public class QueryParam {
    Integer page;
    Integer size;
    /* constructor getter setter */
}
public interface FooMapper {
    @Select("select * from table")
    List<Foo> query(QueryParam param);
}
```

Usage

```java
List<Foo> list = fooMapper.query(new QueryParam(1, 10));
Page<Foo> page = Page.of(list);
```

Done!

Comment: Please read [How Not to be a Spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You must declare affiliation when promoting your own library, otherwise it look like spam. It would also be helpful if you could show how the library can be used to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @DavidBuck Sorry, I've edited the answer